# Как правильно сделать применение одного свойства внутри блока

Tags: html, css, swiper

Как сделать что бы свойство  .swiper-slide  для секции blog работало только в ней а в других секциях у него были стандартные параметры ?

```
.blog>.swiper-slide  и .q123>.swiper-slide
```

такие варианты не заработали

```html
 <section class="blog">
            <p class="blog__subtitle">our resources</p>
            <h2 class="blog__title">Start reading our blog</h2>
            <div class=q123>
                <div class="swiper-container">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="blog__slider-content">
                                <div class="blog__slider-content-image"></div>
                                <div class="blog__slider-content-text">
                                    <h3 class="blog__slider-content-text-title">How to start planning</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Add Pagination -->
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <!-- Add Arrows -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Обычно для этого добавляют дополнительные классы. `.swiper-slide.variant-01`, `.swiper-slide.variant-02` и разносят визуал по ним.

Comment: Cпасибо,разобрался что и как )